# Ordered Integral solutions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> If $a\times b\times c = 12 \times \gcd(a,b,c)$, how many ordered triplets $(a,b,c)$ are possible?

Assuming $a=hx,b=hy,c=hz$ where $h=\gcd(a,b,c)$ .I am getting $h^2xyz=12$.
Solving this I am getting $12$ ordered integral solutions, but the answer given is $21$.

Please can someone help me find out where am I going wrong?

EDIT : The integral solutions I am getting are(1,4,3) arranged by 3!= 6 ways.And (1,2,6) arranged by 3!= 6 ways.
So total = 6+6 =12 solutions.

Comment: What $12$ ordered integral solutions did you find? Telling us this will help us find the ones you missed.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the following solutions by guess and check and rearranging triples with the same numbers.
$$(2,2,6) \text{ yields 3 solutions}$$
$$(1,1,12) \text{ yields 3 solutions}$$
$$(1,2,6) \text{ yields 6 solutions}$$
$$(1,3,4) \text{ yields 6 solutions}$$
$$(2,2,3) \text{ yields 3 solutions}$$
That's $21$ solutions in all.

What you forgot is all of the solutions with repeat numbers. Remember that those still count.